# ITINERARY REQUIRED TO COMPLETE TRANSACTION after enhancedAirTicket Request

Tags: sabre

After I reqeust EnhancedAirTicket, I always get this error. It means booking itinerary is not available? But I always get this error **ITINERARY REQUIRED TO COMPLETE TRANSACTION**. I request EnchancedAirTicket (REST) call. Why do I always get this error?

```
{
  "AirTicketRQ": {
    "DesignatePrinter": {
      "Printers": {
        "Hardcopy":{
            "LNIATA":"xxxxxx",
            "Spacing" : "1"
        },
        "InvoiceItinerary":{
          "LNIATA":"xxxxxx"
        },
        "Ticket": {
          "CountryCode" : "1Y",
          "LNIATA":"xxxxxx"
        }
      }
    },

    "Itinerary": {
      "ID": "UUYCVN"
    },
    "Ticketing": [{
      "FlightQualifiers": {
         "VendorPrefs": {
            "Airline": {
               "Code": "MH"
            }
         }
      },  
      "FOP_Qualifiers": {
        "BasicFOP": {
          "Type":"CA"
        }
      },
      "MiscQualifiers" : {
         "Ticket" : {
            "Type" : "ETR"
         }
      },
      "PricingQualifiers":{
        "PriceQuote":[{
            "NameSelect":[{
                "NameNumber":1.1
            }],
            "Record":[{
                "Number":1
            }]
        }]
      }
    }],
    "PostProcessing": {
      "EndTransaction": {
        "Source": {
          "ReceivedFrom": "SWS TESTING"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you have to check segment status before airticket request. if segment status is not suitable for ticket (for example, status: UC) you'll get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this a couple of times. What happened was that ticketing was successful, but end transaction was done automatically, most likely due to some TJR setting. So when the service tries to end the record with EndTransaction, the PNR was already submitted, hence the "itinerary required..." message.

Comment: So I got this error message, Do I need some set up in TJR setting? How do I solve this error message?

Comment: First of all make sure that the tickets are correctly being attached to your PNR, that is the most important part. Then I'd say you either disable the TJR setting or remove the post processing nodes from air ticket.

Comment: thanks, I can't remove post processing nodes from air ticket because required post processing error. As you said we need to disable post processing in the TJR setting right?